# Water damage? Is this mold? What should we do next?

Tags: mold, water-damage, window-frame

Thoughts on what may have caused this?  Not sure how long it’s been a issue.  Noticed the moisture under the ledge today that led to the discovery of what’s in the picture…. advice on what to do next? In South Carolina

[image]

Comment: Looks like water damage and mold

Answer (score 2):

It's water damage, but the source isn't clear. Could be:

- A leak at the window frame
- A leak at the head of the window or higher up the wall
- A leak at the window sash
- Condensation on the inside

You'll want to track that down with some observation. The fix is basic drywall work:

- Scrape away the loose material. Try not to damage the metal corner bead, if present.
- Use a setting type joint compound for best future moisture resistance (as opposed to premix) to fill and skim.
- Sand, prime, paint.

I don't worry much about mold. Unless you're overly sensitive or there's a huge amount of it, that's just life. Mold is already everywhere.